# Javafx how to fix a Node inside a ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, nodes, scrollpane

I have many nodes in a ScrollPane and I would like some of them to stay at a fixed position even if the user scrolls horizontally or vertically.

Comment: Put the `ScrollPane` and the fixed nodes in a `Pane` (or possibly `StackPane`).

Comment: Have you tried something to achieve this? If yes, I would like to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: what @James_D suggested worked. I used a StackPane.